# What is the "upcoming source book" mentioned in Shadowrun 4 FAQ?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, books, product-identification

In the [SR4 FAQ](http://www.shadowrun4.com/game-resources/frequently-asked-questions/), the answer to several questions about magic is "This question will be answered fully in an upcoming sourcebook."

The questions unanswered include the following little wonders:

> If you enchant a car as a focus, can you run someone’s astral form
> over with it?

or

> Can you attack a target on the astral using a dual-natured metahuman
> or critter as an improvised melee weapon?

It doesn't seem to be Street Magic, or any of the "main" supplements, as they are mentioned in the FAQ, and it was updated long after Street Magic or the other books were published.

Does someone know what book it refers to?

Comment: It's probably something to expand on the different worlds. Probably a whole book about Astral and another one about Wireless (next)

Comment: Since the FAQ calls it "upcoming", it presumably doesn't have a title yet. Expect the FAQ to be updated when the book is released.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. Since the FAQ is 9 months old, I supposed the book could have been released by now, but doesn't seem so. Well, I will probably let the question open until the concerned book gets released.

Comment: Given that SR5 is due this year, it looks like SR 4 has reached the end of the road, and that promised supplement won't see the light of day, at least for SR 4.

Answer (score 6):

No. Those questions aren't answered in any book that I know of.

However, I would use the 1st rule of role-playing games: 
*Have fun*

Albeit the SR4A rules are pretty complete, those corner cases aren't covered for good reason: One cannot anticipate everything.

Therefore it should be up to the story-teller if those works, and it should serve the purpose of having fun.